# Malloc call as a function argument

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have the following function in my program:

```
char *strconcat(char *str1, char *str2);
```

This function performs a malloc call to allocate the concatenation of both strings.

This string will be therefore used in a function like this:

```
void myFunction(char *inputstr);
```

Normally, I use the function as follows:

```
mystring = strconcat(mystr1, mystr2);
myFunction(mystring);
```

Is it possible to perform the call like this?

```
myFunction(strconcat(mystr1, mystr2));
```

Is the allocated memory deallocated or there will be memory lakes before this call? Using the function like this, I haven't any reference to the allocated memory so I cannot use free.

Thank you in advance.

Alex

Comment: Where are you calling `free`? If the answer is "nowhere", you have a memory leak.

Comment: yes, but do not forget to free(inputstr); in myFunction

Comment: @Manül Yes that would work but I'd argue it's not very good design and very fragile.

Comment: @larsmans, in the second call I do not call free anywhere. That's my question, ¿Are there memory leaks even if I don't have a pointer that reference this memory area? The answer seems to be YES

Comment: @alexag: that's pretty much the *definition* of a memory leak.

Comment: @larsmans, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to perform the call like this?
>
> ```
> myFunction(strconcat(mystr1, mystr2));
> ```

Yes, you can. The function argument should be an expression and that expression evaluated before passing to (copying to) function parameter. Therefore `strconcat(mystr1, mystr2)` will be evaluated and the returned result will copied to parameter of the function `myFunction`. You have to deallocate memory in function to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. The problem is that I cannot deallocate memory in `myFunction` because in other situations `myString` needs to be used after the function call. So I suppose that I must use the function as in my first option to have a reference to the memory area and deallocate it outside `myFunction`.